# Windows 11 Minecraft version 1.19.62 won't reset my spawn point

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Just downloaded Minecraft for windows.  I have Windows 11.  When I sleep my spawn point says it is reset but when I die I respawn at my original spawn point for the world.  Is there a fix for this?
(I did break my bed and take it with me)
I have found out that if I sleep in a bed and leave the bed in place I will respawn to that location unless I sleep again elsewhere and break the bed I am carrying with me.  Then I respawn to the original world location again.
Perhaps this is the way it is supposed to work??
Can we have only one respawn point and must leave a bed intact at that location?

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Comment: No I am not.  it is a fresh download last night.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one respawn point, and yes your bed must stay intact.

> If a player's bed is absent, or if the area around the bed is made unsuitable for respawning (see below), a message is displayed saying You have no home bed or respawn anchor, or it was obstructed‌[Java Edition only]/Your home bed was missing or obstructed‌[Bedrock Edition only], and the player respawns at the world spawn point.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Setting_the_spawn_point)